# Why is my onclick function not running on first click but running fine second click onwards

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, getelementbyid

PS - I am a non tech person but can create basic websites for small personal projects.
I was working on a simple website where I needed to add a modal form using HTML/JS (Code below) and when I run it, it does not load the modal form on first click but works fine on the second click onwards. Tried researching but couldnt find anything or couldnt understand a lot of stuff.
(The above code was derived from a form tutorial on W3schools)

**EDIT** - I am using the (fid) variable as I need to call this same function multiple times on the page, hence not using "mybtn" directly in document.getElementById(fid)

```js
< script >
   function myfunc(fid) {
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      var btn = document.getElementById(fid);
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      btn.onclick = function () {
         modal.style.display = "block";
      };
      span.onclick = function () {
         modal.style.display = "none";
      };
      window.onclick = function (event) {
         if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
         }
      };
   }
   < /script>
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" class="btn" onclick="myfunc('myBtn')">Enquire Now</a>
```

Comment: because you only add the listener once `myfunc` is called on the first click.

Comment: because you **multiply** the listener instance only after button first clicked event

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set the event listeners programmatically

```
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  };
  span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
</script>
```

And then remove the onclick from the button element.

```
<a id="myBtn" class="btn">Enquire Now</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the desired effect with a single delegated event handler that responds to `click` events on some designated ancestor element... here it is the `document` itself. The `click` will trigger an `event` that can be processed in the callback function to determine ( thanks to event bubbling/propagation ) which element triggered the callback and thus you can run whatever code you need within the suitably partitioned pieces of code.

```js
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  
  let dialog=document.querySelector('#myModal');
  let span=dialog.querySelector('span.close');
  
  if( e.target.id=='myBtn' ){
    dialog.style.display='block'
  }
  
  if(e.target.className=='close' ){
    dialog.style.display='none'
  }
  
});
```

```css
.close{
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:3rem;
}
.close:before{
  content:'X';
  color:white;
  font-size:3rem;
  cursor:pointer
}
#myModal{
  display:none;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:1rem;
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:auto;
  padding:1rem;
  float:none;
}

.btn{
  display:block;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1rem;
  background:whitesmoke;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  margin:1rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" class="btn">Enquire Now</a>

<div id='myModal'>
  <span class='close'></span>
</div>
```